# Capture the log hourly from daily log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a log file which is daily rotate( let say main log file) I need capture the log hourly up-to now then store the hourly log file

Ex;

When I execute the script command at 02/06/2017  03:41:35 I need logs between 02:41:35 to 03:41:35

Main log file

```
[02/06/2017][00:12:41][58162][3690952448][000000000000000000000000
[02/06/2017][00:12:41][58162][3690952448][000000000000000000000000
----------
[02/06/2017][03:41:35][57732][3674167040][000000000000000000000000
[02/06/2017][03:41:35][57732][3674167040][000000000000000000000000
```

hourly log file

```
[02/06/2017][02:41:35][58162][3690952448][000000000000000000000000
[02/06/2017][02:41:35][58162][3690952448][000000000000000000000000
----------
[02/06/2017][03:41:35][57732][3674167040][000000000000000000000000
[02/06/2017][03:41:35][57732][3674167040][000000000000000000000000
```

I have execute the below commands, but it’s not capturing hourly log instead of capturing all the logs

```
echo $(date -d'now-1 hours' +"[%d/%m/%Y][%H:%M:%S]") | cat mainlog.log 
echo $(date --date='1 hours ago' +"[%d/%m/%Y][%H:%M:%S]") | cat mainlog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You are piping the output of `echo` into `cat` - that won't filter anything.  `cat` will ignore the input coming through the pipe (stdin) since it is reading from the file `mainlog.log`.

You could do this instead (note the change in date format - I have removed the `%M` and `%S` parts):

```
grep -F "$(date -d'now-1 hours' +'[%d/%m/%Y][%H:]')" mainlog.log 
grep -F "$(date -d'1 hours ago' +'[%d/%m/%Y][%H:]')" mainlog.log
```

Here, `grep` would look for the string returned by the `date` command in your log file.

Comment: I have try using grep at the first time like u mention above , but result is same , not capturing result between hourly log it's getting/capturing all the logs . if you have "smtrace_apache" log can see the same :)

Comment: Please check the updated answer.  Probably, the lack of `-F` option was causing an issue.  Also, I changed the date format.

Comment: after puttng -F option it will not providing/grepping any result , anyway thanks for you input herewith